# Case when clause in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I am working on an existing extraction and must add two new view tables. If condition A, use V1, else use V2.

```
select ...
case when pr.flg_mpa = 'Y' then V1.vol when pr.flg_mpa != 'Y' then V2.vol end as vol

from ...V1, V2

 where ...
 V2.num_uat = lo.num_uat AND
 V2.typ_uat = lo.typ_uat AND 
 V2.cle_lit = tc.cle_lit AND

 V1.num_uat = lo.num_uat AND
 V1.typ_uat = lo.typ_uat AND  
 V1.num_ligne =pd.num_ligne AND
```

When pr.flg_mpa = 'Y', vol returns 0, which is incorrect. When pr.flg_mpa != 'Y', the entire row vanishes.

I began testing to write them separately.

```
    select ...
    V1.vol as vol1,
    V2.vol as vol2,
  
    from ...V1, V2

    where ...
    V2.num_uat = lo.num_uat AND
    V2.typ_uat = lo.typ_uat AND 
    V2.cle_lit = tc.cle_lit AND

    V1.num_uat = lo.num_uat AND
    V1.typ_uat = lo.typ_uat AND  
    V1.num_ligne =pd.num_ligne AND
```

The result is the same as above.

```
   select ...
    V1.vol as vol1
         
    from ...V1

    where ...
    V1.num_uat = lo.num_uat AND
    V1.typ_uat = lo.typ_uat AND  
    V1.num_ligne =pd.num_ligne AND
```

When pr.flg_mpa = 'Y', the result is correct.

```
select ...
    V2.vol as vol
  
    from ...V2

    where ...
    V2.num_uat = lo.num_uat AND
    V2.typ_uat = lo.typ_uat AND 
    V2.cle_lit = tc.cle_lit AND
```

When pr.flg_mpa ！= 'Y', the result is correct.

Is there anything wrong? Thank you in advance.

Comment: is there a chance pr.flg_mpa is NULL, in such cases the comparison operators will not work, in such cases you might have to use nullif and compare.

Comment: A complete test case would make this easier to answer.

Comment: Please, provide some sample data and expected result. We know nothing about your data nor objects hidden behind aliases lo, tc, pd, pr ...

Answer (score 1):

A `case` cannot make a row vanish.  What part of your `where` clause could filter out rows where `pr.flg_mpa != 'Y'`?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by accident, with right join in where clause then the result won't disappear.

```
SELECT *
from SAT_ORDR O, V1, V2

where 
  V1.num_uat(+) = O.num_uat AND
  V1.typ_uat(+) = O.typ_uat AND  
  V2.num_uat(+) = O.num_uat AND
  V2.typ_uat(+)= O.typ_uat
```